# Join a raster file with grid data and a CSV file

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, csv, grids-graticules

I am a relatively new user of QGIS and encoutered a first major problem.

I am working with this dataset that converts the available geocoordinates into the European standard ETRS89-LAEA.This is a grid of 1-square-meter raster cells covering all of
Germany. It does not contain the specific longitudes and latitudes for the objects in the dataset.

The data is available as a

- CSV file that contains all the variables, also containing the grid
  cells
- a raster file that only shows the location of each raster

Now I want to join both files so that the raster file that indicates the location in QGIS contains the data of the CSV file.

This does not work out: I used the command `Join attributes by location` but it does not find the csv file. I think the problem lies in the fact that the spatial dimension of the csv file is not recognized.

How can I change that and produce a join as described above?

Comment: Did you try adding the [csv file as a vector layer?](https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/ImportData)

Comment: Yes, I indeed tried that. If you use ´´´Join attributes by location´´´ it does not even display the csv file (added as vector layer) due to the missing spatial index.